# Unable to find working route - No route matches {:action=>"show", :controller=>"users"}

Tags: ruby-on-rails

No route matches {:action=>"show", :controller=>"users"}

Working with a condition current_page in rails with this format. Trying to not render a navbar within users/show path, but it should be visible in the rest of site. One thing to note is that the users/show URL has been configured in routes.rb to not show '/users/' folder in the URL, so it looks like 'mysite.com/username'

```
    <% if current_page?(controller: 'users', action: 'show') %>
    no navbar
    <% else %>
    <%= render partial: "shared/navbar" %>
    <% end %>
```

The first condition works fine, however when I reach a page that should match the 'else' condition, for instance my root_path, I get this error:

```
    ActionController::UrlGenerationError in Dashboard#show
    Showing /Users/javier/Desktop/rails-apps/testtradus3/app/views/shared/_navbar.html.erb where line #1 raised:

    No route matches {:action=>"show", :controller=>"users"}
```

My route.rb looks like this

```
    # For details on the DSL available within this file, see http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html
    Rails.application.routes.draw do
    ...

      # This removes '/users/' from user/show URI
      resources :users, path: '', :only => [:show]

      # User account
      devise_for :users,
        controllers: {
          omniauth_callbacks: "users/omniauth_callbacks",
          registrations: "users/registrations",
          sessions: "users/sessions"
        }
      devise_scope :user do
        get "session/otp", to: "sessions#otp"
      end

      resources :users do
        resources :builduser, controller: 'users/builduser'
      end

    ...

    end
```

This returns this rails routes:

users GET    /users(.:format)               users#index
POST   /users(.:format)               users#create

I have tried removing the custom path in routes.rb, so something like resources :users and that returns these routes
users GET    /users(.:format)                                                                                  users#index
POST   /users(.:format)                                                                                 users#create

```
          GET    /users(.:format)                                                                                  users#index
          POST   /users(.:format)                                                                                 users#create
          GET    /users/new(.:format)                                                                              users#new
          GET    /users/:id/edit(.:format)                                                                         users#edit
          GET    /users/:id(.:format)                                                                              users#show
```

My UsersController.rb

```
    class UsersController < ApplicationController

        def index
            @users = User.all
        end

        def show            
            @user = User.friendly.find(params[:id])
            @order = Order.new
        end


        def create
            @user = User.new(user_params)
            
            respond_to do |format|
                if @user.save
                # format.html { redirect_to @order, notice: "Order was successfully created." }
                # Added this one below:
                format.html { redirect_to user_builduser_index_path(@user)}
                format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @user }
                else
                format.html { render :new, status: :unprocessable_entity }
                format.json { render json: @user.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
                end      
            end
        end
    ..
    end
```

Comment: One thing to keep in mind if you're letting users have links to `/user_name_here` on your site is that if it becomes popular you're crowding out your own options for declaring routes. While you can use an extensive blacklist of allowed names its hard to actually know what you'll need in the future. Reddit for example was smart to use `/u/username`.

Comment: I have the same problem with `current_page? controller: 'restaurants', action: 'page'`... the route exists, but I get the `No route matches` error. Have you found a solution?

Comment: This works: `controller_name == 'restaurants' && action_name == 'page'`. It seems that `current_page?` also expects the id param.

Answer (score 0):

Going off some of the examples listed in the link below, you could try:

```
current_page?(users_path(current_user))
# or
current_page?(users_path(@user))
# or even
current_page?("/#{@user&.id}")
```

An alternative could be to set a `before_action` in your `ApplicationController` to set an instance variable:

```
before_action :display_nav_bar # this would apply to all routes unless overridden like below in the UsersController

def display_nav_bar
  @display_nav_bar = true
end

# and in your UsersController:

def show
  @display_nav_bar = false
  # other stuff
  @user = User.find(params[:id)
end
```

then

```
<% if @display_nav_bar %>
    <%= render partial: "shared/navbar" %>
<% else %>
    no navbar
<% end %>
```

You could also look into using layouts for different controllers and control rendering the nav bar that way.

[current_page? source](https://apidock.com/rails/v5.2.3/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper/current_page%3F)